# Hölder type inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I was reading a paper and I found stated without proof or reference the following inequality:

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}\prod_{j=1}^{n}(\beta_{i}^j)^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq \prod_{j=1}^{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left(\beta_{i}^{j}\right)^{p_j}\right)^{\frac{1}{p_j}}$$

where $\beta_i^j\geq 0$ and $\frac{1}{p_1}+\cdots\frac{1}{p_n}=\frac{1}{p}$

Anyone knows where I can find a proof for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [generalized Hölder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Generalization_of_H.C3.B6lder.27s_inequality) with counting measure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Milind!